# DOM Exception 12 Using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile app using jquery-mobile v1.1 and I'm running into a (caught) DOM Exception 12 error when navigating to another page within the app. The offending block starts on line 5197 in the jquery.js file and is this:

```
try {
    // This should fail with an exception
    // Gecko does not error, returns false instead
    matches.call( document.documentElement, "[test!='']:sizzle" );
} catch( pseudoError ) {
    pseudoWorks = true;
}
```

The page registers that an error has occurred but it doesn't block any actions and everything works as expected however an 'error loading page' label appears briefly on the screen.

Caveat:

*The error does not get thrown in Firefox, but does get thrown in Chrome and on Mobile Safari.

Comment: If possible, use jQuery Mobile 1.2. There has been a lot of changes since 1.1 and you may be dealing with a jQuery Mobile 1.1 issue that has been fixed already.

Comment: ok awesome thanks. The issue ended up being resolved by removing an evt.preventDefault() nested somewhere in our own code

Comment: @BobbyS. Can you put it as an answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this specific issue seems to be resolved but it hasn't been addressed in an answer, I'll make the general remark that when trying to debug an error that pops up in the jQuery/jQuery UI/etc files, it's usually not actually an error IN THAT FILE, it's an error in your usage of it that isn't actually breaking until it gets down into jQuery. So you really want to just figure out "what Javascript that I wrote was being run right before that broke?", and start there.